# How do describe the composition of an indicator function?

Tags: linear-algebra, function-and-relation-composition

I have an indicator function:

[image]

I have to describe the composition in this form:

[image]

I replaced the 'n' value with the function but I cannot simplify it, how can one describe and simplify the composition of an indicator function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Calculate $f(f(n))$ for $0\le n\le4$, for $n=5, 6$, and for $n>6$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is this the usual method? How did you choose those 'n' values?

Comment: It's specific to this exercise. If you make the calculations, you might have a guess why those values of $n$ are differentiated.